Is the spectral radius continuous around the left-shift operator?
I'm interested in the spectral radius of perturbations to the left-shift operator $T$ on $\ell^2$.  I know that the spectral radius is $r(T)=1$ and that $r(\cdot)$ is upper semi-continuous, but not generally continuous.  So I would like to know if there exists an arbitrarily small perturbation $\epsilon$ such that $r(T+\epsilon)<<1$, i.e. is $r(\cdot)$ discontinuous at $T$?
I have found examples of perturbations yielding discontinuities in the spectrum in older books considering some generalized left-shift operators on the bi-infinite $\ell^2$, but nothing for the canonical left-shift operator (i.e. on sequences indexed by $\mathbb{N}$).
Thanks!

No, $r(\cdot)$ is in fact continuous at $T$. We first consider the right shift. Let $S$ be the right-shift operator, which is an isometry. Let $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and let $Q$ be any operator with $\|Q\| \leq \epsilon$. Then as $S$ is an isometry, we have, for all $v \in H$, $\|(S + Q)v\| \geq (1 - \epsilon)\|v\|$, so by induction,
$$\|(S + Q)^nv\| \geq (1 - \epsilon)^n\|v\|$$
Which implies $\|(S + Q)^n\| \geq (1 - \epsilon)^n$. But then, by taking conjugates,
$$\|(T + Q)^n\| = \|[(T + Q)^n]^\ast\| = \|(S + Q^\ast)^n\| \geq (1 - \epsilon)^n$$
where we have used the fact that $\|Q\| \leq \epsilon$ implies $\|Q^\ast\| \leq \epsilon$. But then, by spectral radius formula,
$$r(T + Q) = \lim_n \|(T + Q)^n\|^{1/n} \geq \limsup_n [(1 - \epsilon)^n]^{1/n} = 1 - \epsilon$$
On the other hand, as $\|T\| = 1$, we have $\|T + Q\| \leq 1 + \epsilon$, so $r(T + Q) \leq 1 + \epsilon$ as well. That is, whenever $\|Q\| \leq \epsilon$, we have,
$$1 - \epsilon \leq r(T + Q) \leq 1 + \epsilon$$
So precisely that $r(\cdot)$ is continuous at $T$.

This, in effect, shows $r(\cdot)$ is continuous at any isometry or co-isometry.

Terrific, thank you.
A (tougher) follow-up question: is the point spectrum itself continuous at $T$? i.e. the point spectrum for $T$ is the interior of the unit disc.  Are there arbitrarily small perturbations that can add holes in the spectrum, even though they cannot affect the radius?

@Stig That’s an interesting question. I’m not sure. I’m inclined to think at least the point spectrum shouldn’t be preserved, but I couldn’t find a good counterexample.
